# how to config the path of SDK in androidStudio with non ascii character?

Tags: windows, android-studio, sdk

i'm installing this android studio SW and getting this error MSG:

```
your SDK location contains non-ASCII character
```

my laptop's lang. is Hebrew. 
may ichange manual the path of the SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just change your user name something else that not contains non-Ascii character. Ex. `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\...` You should use the English language. You can learn Ascii vs non-Ascii from [here](https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/what-is-ascii)

Also, you can use a different locations for Android SDK that not contains any non-ASCII character.

Comment: may i name the folder any name?

Comment: yes, Just be sure that you don't use non-ascii character